# How to make custom collection editable in DataGrid in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have business object class that contains definition of `List<T>` for other business objects.

I cannot change class structure, so I cannot simply use `ObservableCollection<T>` instead of `List<T>` but I want to leverage [`ObservableCollection<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1?view=netframework-4.7.2) functionality. So I created a sort of a observable collection wrapper class like this (also tried it with `IList<T>` instead of `ICollection<T>`).

```
public class CollectionObservableOverlay<T> : ICollection<T>, INotifyCollectionChanged
{
    protected ICollection<T> _wrappedCollection;

    #region ICollection<T> properties
    public int Count { get { return _wrappedCollection.Count; } }

    public bool IsReadOnly { get { return _wrappedCollection.IsReadOnly; } }
    #endregion

    public event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged;

    public CollectionObservableOverlay(ICollection<T> wrappedCollection)
    {
        _wrappedCollection = wrappedCollection;
    }

    protected void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        CollectionChanged?.Invoke(this, e);
    }

    #region ICollection<T> methods

    public void Add(T item)
    {
        _wrappedCollection.Add(item);
        OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add, item));

    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        _wrappedCollection.Clear();
        OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
    }

    public bool Contains(T item)
    {
        return _wrappedCollection.Contains(item);
    }

    public void CopyTo(T[] array, int arrayIndex)
    {
        CopyTo(array, arrayIndex);
    }

    public virtual bool Remove(T item)
    {
        bool removed = _wrappedCollection.Remove(item);
        OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
        return removed;
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _wrappedCollection.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return ((IEnumerable)_wrappedCollection).GetEnumerator();
    }
    #endregion
}
```

The problem is, when I bind instance of `CollectionObservableOverlay` to `DataGrid` as `ItemsSource` and try to edit items, i get the following error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException
  HResult=0x80131509
  Message='EditItem' is not allowed for this view.
  Source=PresentationFramework
```

I tried binding to underlying collection directly, and that works fine for `DataGrid` editing purposes, so underlying list or it's contained objects should not be the source of the problem.

My guess is that I am missing some functionalities which are implemented in concrete `List<T>` type, but are not present at `IList<T>` or `ICollection<T>` interfaces.

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181519/custom-collection-crashes-datagrid-on-edit), and [other related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4691453/what-conditions-have-to-be-fulfilled-in-order-to-edit-custom-collection-via-wpf) questions and answers but none of them are providing solution on how to do this, or answer if it is even possible. As far as I understand, [`ICollectionView`](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.icollectionview?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) provided to `DataGrid` should implement [`IEditableCollectionView`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.ieditablecollectionview?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2), but I don't know how to achieve that kind of behavior. Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your source collection must implement the non-generic `IList` interface for the internal editing functionality of the `DataGrid` control to work as expected.

`List<T>` and `ObservableCollection<T>` do this but `HashSet<T>` doesn't for example.

Comment: But my source collection is of type List<T> as stated at the top of my question. And i also tried to use IList<T> instead of ICollection<T> for wrapper class, and it still doesn't work.

Comment: @Miljac: No. `CollectionObservableOverlay<T>` is not a `List<T>`. And it doesn't implement the non-generic `IList` interface. Implementing the generic `IList<T>` interface is not enough.

Comment: I totally missed that non-generic part, I totally overlooked it altogether, thank you for pointing that out, It works now